# My careers profile link gives an error on mobile devices

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, mobile-web

When I go to my careers profile special url, https://careers.stackoverflow.com/pimvandongen

It gives an error. Of the "Oops something bad happened sort". I wanted to show my resume to someone today, but I'm not sure it will even work.

I'm using Android with Chrome. I'm also logged in when I try to view my profile via the special link.

When I select that I want to view the desktop version it works. I checked with an incognito tab and it doesnt seem that being logged in matters.

Comment: Careers has no mobile theme, retagging. ([tag:mobile-web] is for questions about the mobile theme of Stack Exchange sites)

Comment: Anyway reproduced with both Chrome and Safari on iPhone (iOS) so it's not specific to android or Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The answer claims there are mobile-only layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Can't repro this anymore but I suspect it was due to a change that affected mobile-only layouts. It has since been rectified!